# how to kill or quit .exe(debugging)application in c#

Tags: c#

Hello i've got some code ,to check if is there a specific folder created, it will zip the file in the folder, and if there isn't a folder created , quit the app.

```
 try
            {
                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary = true;
                    zip.AddDirectory(@"C:\" + tglskrg + "\\Result");
                    zip.Save(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), tglskrg + ".zip"));
                    zip.Save(@"C:\Users\Desktop\test.zip");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWS);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);

                    xlApp.Quit(); // release excel object
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
               //code to quit the .exe app
            }
...
//send email code : which its work
```

I dont know how to kill the .exe app when its not success finding the folder.
i know to kill other process like notepad ,other  apps , but i dont know how to kill this debug .exe app, i hope u guys understand because my english is so bad

Thankyouu

Comment: Why are you manually performing garbage collection?

Comment: hmm i just follow the code where my senior use it before ..

Comment: `Environment.Exit(1)`, and please, do not mess with `GC`

Comment: hmm what does GC do?

Comment: @Enrico Garbage collection disposes of _managed_ objects which are no longer referenced.

Comment: @EnricoHasnawi, a lot of nasty and scary things that you shouldn't worry about

Comment: Are you trying to kill **your** process, or `Excel`?

Comment: You can't just check if folder exist and then try to save your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Application.Exit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=netframework-4.8). If I understood your question correctly, it is what you need.

The above method, as vasily.sib said, is for `WinForms`. For WPF you can use [Application.shutDown()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdown?view=netframework-4.8) and for general you can use [Environment.Exit(int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netframework-4.8)